# Using variables / node information in technique?

Tags: rudder

I am trying to update a config file using  the "File Enforce Content" in the Lines argument I have tried obtaining information about the node using `${rudder.node.hostname}` this never gets replaced on the actual node though and remains the same?  I am actually after the IP address of the node as well as the host name but using this to test the technique is working [since the docs mention it](https://www.rudder-project.org/doc-4.1/_variables.html#_system_variables).

Lines Parameter

```
[Config]
IP=${rudder.node.ipaddress}
Name=${rudder.node.hostname}
```

Nodes file

```
[Config]
IP=${rudder.node.ipaddress}
Name=${rudder.node.hostname}
```

Expected

```
[Config]
IP=10.0.0.1
Name=node1
```

(Just as a side note I am struggling to locate a list in the web portal or online of available replacement variables so the ip address one is probably wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Variables computed by Rudder (ie rudder.node.hostname) cannot be used directly for now in techniques created with the technique editor. (I haven't manage to find the bug https://www.rudder-project.org/redmine/projects/rudder/issues, but there should be one, or you can open a new one if you want)

A workaround can be to create variable with the variable technique like the following screenshot

[image: define rudder variable]

and access the variable in technique editor like this:

> ${generic_variable_definition.hostname}

I think we will work soon on this issue to provide you a way to use it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use

${sys.host} 
${sys.ipv4}
${sys.host}

The definitions I found here:
[CFEngine Special Variables](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.10/reference-special-variables-sys.html)